# Nextjs pages using useEffect can't be make a server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm considering moving from react to nextjs and i have some issues with comprehension of server side rendering.

If my page contains a component with a use effect (for example i use a component with threejs which use useEffect hook), nextjs will render the entire page with Client side rendering (same of react) and not server side rendering ? So nextjs in this case is useless ? Same case, sometimes i use useEffect with window.addEventListener to add some scroll effect so i can't make server side renderind on this component.
So it's possible to make a hybrid SSR and CSR on the same page ? (for example CSR with components that use useEffect hook and others components use SSR for static component on the same page)

If i need to update data on pages for example each one seconds, if i use SSR, the http request is send to server which make an other http request to get data, generate an other html and send the new html page with update data to client side ? It seems to me to take longer to regenerate the page than to make the client-side request directly to obtain the data.

I expected to use SSR and CSR on the same page to using powerfull of SSR to generate html and use CSR just on specific component on the same page to make effect (like threejs, scroll effect...etc) with nextjs but i don't now if it's possible.

Comment: Next.js is versatile and can handle a mix of SSR, CSR, and SSG on the same page. You can use SSR for the initial page load, client-side rendering for dynamic and interactive parts, and static generation for parts that don't change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> So it's possible to make a hybrid SSR and CSR on the same page ?

Yes !

> If i need to update data on pages for example each one seconds, if i use SSR, the http request is send to server which make an other http request to get data, generate an other html and send the new html page with update data to client side ?

CSR, because rest of the static content on page will be as it is. If you do SSR, whole page will be re-rendered & states will be re-initialized.
If you have useEffect, useStates...etc in your page NextJS won't even allow you to make that page (it throw error)

**Solution** :

- Just make a component, at top add `'use client'` directive  import this component in a page.

**Here's a small code I made :**

**Folder Structure :**

I'm using app router, & i have excluded extra folders & files.

```
projectName
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── api
│       ├── comp
│       │   ├── Hybrid.js
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── hybrid
│       │   └── page.js
│       ├── layout.js
│       ├── page.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

**Hybrid.js** is a component present in `comp` folder `projectName\src\app\comp\Hybrid.js`:

```
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Hybrid = () => {

    async function CallProductsAPI() {
        let tmp = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
        let data = await tmp.json()
        console.log("Data from API : ", data);
        // VISIBLE IN BROWSER CONSOLE
        SetProducts(data)
    }

    const [Products, SetProducts] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        CallProductsAPI()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Products Page</h1>
            {
                Products

                    ?
                    Products.products.slice(0, 5).map((p, i) => {
                        // DATA IS INSIDE products key
                        // LOTS OF DATA, HENCE slice(0,5) to show 5 results
                        return (
                            <h6 key={i} onClick={() => { alert(p.title + "Clicked !") }}>{p.title}</h6>
                        )
                    })
                    :

                    "Loading Products ...."
                // THIS LOADING STATE WILL  BE VISIBLE BECAUSE CLIENT LOADS A SECTION OF PAGE 

            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hybrid
```

**page.js** (file name according to app router file convention) `projectName\src\app\hybrid\page.js`:

```
import Hybrid from "../comp/Hybrid"

const page = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hybrid Page</h1>

            <Hybrid />

            <h3>Rest of the page is rendered by server.</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default page
```

**Explaination :**

- I have made a Hybrid page, which calls api from useEffect.
- I have made a Client side component, which makes a API call & sets data in state & then updates in DOM.
- To add interactivity, if you click on those product names alert will be shown.
- Then I have page.js, which is rendered by server.
- I imported this component, in page.

**Output:**

- Go to `http://localhost:3000/hybrid`, open console & navigate to `Network Tab`
- Under `Name tab`, you will see `hybrid`. Click on it & on right handside click on `Preview`
- You will see pre-rendered page (SSR+CSR implemented !).
- You might be wondering, how is `Loading Products ....` visible ? Next.js uses React's APIs to render a static HTML preview on the server for both Client and Server Components. *(Read Full page load, link given below)*
- Try removing `use client` & see, error : `You're importing a component that needs useState.`

***Please Read :***

- **'use client'** : https://react.dev/reference/react/use-client
- **Rendering :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering
- **Server Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components
- **Client Components :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
- **Benefits of Server Rendering :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#benefits-of-server-rendering
- **Server and Client Composition Patterns :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns
- What is the React Server Component Payload (RSC)? : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#how-are-server-components-rendered
- **How are Client Components Rendered?** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#how-are-client-components-rendered
- Full page load : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#full-page-load
- Subsequent Navigations : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#subsequent-navigations

> ***If you have any doubts, leave a comment.***

Comment: thanks, it's much clearer. Right now, i use threejs for the first content of my page (single page application). So other contents have time to load before user go it and SEO is not a priority. Next time i use this framework, very powerfull.

Comment: You may mark a answer accepted,  Please read : 
*What should I do when someone answers my question?* : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers